# What is wrong with this URL rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want (for example)

```
discuss/1/title/where-are-you
```

to output

```
discussPage.php?id=1&title=where-are-you
```

I have the following commands in a `.htaccess` file which is in the same directory as `discussPage.php`:

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite user URLs
#   Input:  discuss/ID/title/TITLE
#   Output: discussPage.php?tid=NAME&title=TITLE

RewriteRule ^discuss/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ discussPage.php?id=$1&title=$3
```

Right now I am getting a `404` error when I try to visit a page like `discuss/1/title/where-are-you` even though `discussPage.php?id=1&title=where-are-you works fine.`

P.S. `mod_rewrite` is enabled (i have used it for other purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that \w does not match the "-" in the last bit.

You can simply allow dashes in there using a broader character class like `[\w-]+`. I would be careful with solutions like `[^/]` because they allow *anything except a slash*, which is quite permissive. White-lists are always safer and avoid surprises.

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite user URLs
#   Input:  discuss/ID/title/TITLE
#   Output: discussPage.php?tid=NAME&title=TITLE

RewriteRule ^discuss/(\w+)/(\w+)/([\w-]+)/?$ discussPage.php?id=$1&title=$3
```

Note that the `-` has to be last in the character class, otherwise you should escape it, because if it's in between two other characters it behaves as a range, like in `[a-z]`.

Answer (score -1):

To debug, you can always `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

But I believe the correct code would be something like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^discuss/([0-9]+)/title/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ discussPage.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

You might want to fix your RewriteBase value, though.

Also - as seen in the last condition, you can only have alphanumeric characters and hyphens in the `where-are-you` part. (but something tells me you won't be needing other characters!)

Answer (score -2):

Works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^discuss/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ discussPage.php?id=$1&title=$3 [R]
```

Comment: @Teneff: Almost. You missed that \w is not matching -, as others said. Anyway, algorithmicCoder is in downgrading mood today.